# Fit: Experimental`NumericalFunction error when fitting a black-box function

Tags: numerics, bugs, fitting

**Bug appearing in at least 12.0.0 and 12.3.1**

I'm trying some multidimensional Chebyshev fits. First, define a wrapper to prevent premature symbolic evaluation (I don't want a power series result):

```
cheb[n_Integer, x_?NumericQ] := ChebyshevT[n, x]
```

Function to construct list of basis functions for `Fit`:

```
chebasis[vars_List, n_Integer] := 
  Flatten@Outer[Times, Sequence @@ 
  Transpose@Table[cheb[i, #] & /@ vars, {i, 0, n}]]
```

Now, make some test data:

```
tdata = N[Flatten[Table[{x, y, x y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 1]];
```

Attempt a fit:

```
Fit[tdata, chebasis[{x, y}, 1], {x, y}] // Chop
```

Emits an error message:

```
Experimental`NumericalFunction::dimsl: {y} given in {x,y} should be a list of dimensions for a particular argument.
```

It does, however yield a sensible result:

```
1. cheb[1, x] cheb[1, y]
```

So, what's going on here? Is it harmless? Can I avoid it?

Comment: For whatever it's worth the "equivalent" fit with `NonlinearModelFit` (`NonlinearModelFit[tdata, {a1, a2, a3, a4} . chebasis[{x, y}, 1], {a1, a2, a3, a4}, {x, y}] // Chop`) gives the same error message and fit.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* (not vague, cutesy, and confusing) title.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If you don't have something constructive to offer, please don't comment.

Comment: @John Doty:  This *IS* a constructive comment.  It points out a weakness.  Innumerable other comments are the same, saying a question is (for instance), too vague, or unclear, or needs more work, or should be typeset.  I expect you complain about such thousands of comments too, right?  Oh... what is "the beast", specifically?  And "annoys"?

Comment: This is just a comment and not an explanation.  If you remove the `?NumericQ`, it works fine with the result being `1. x y`.

Comment: @JimB It works, but yields a power series result, which is what I'm trying to avoid with the wrapper. Might as well just use `ChebyshevT` without wrapping it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Are you campaigning for election to the office of Beast? Apparently, I've annoyed you more than I've annoyed the machinery behind `Fit` ツ

Comment: Thanks.  I should learn how to read (as that's in your first paragraph).

Comment: I have to say I agree with @DavidG.Stork. The purpose of a good title is so that future users searching in stack exchange for a similar question should be able to find this one and therefore not write a duplicate. It also serves the purpose of giving potential answerers a quick idea of what the question is about, which allows them to waste less time clicking through (or wasting your time by not clicking through due to the title not having enough information about the question).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm considering adding the bugs tag. I can reproduce this error in version`12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)`.

Comment: @march Somehow I didn’t get pinged, but I agree it’s a bug.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Is AlexeyPopkov's new title tedious enough to make you happy?

Comment: What does "tedious" have to do with anything?  But yes... it is surely an improvement upon the vague, uninformative, cutesy title ("beast"... *really*?!) that, the OP should learn, no faculty member or potential employer would countenance.  I presume you agree it is an improvement since you (apparently) made the change.  (Thanks.)  The title could be improved to relate to the relevant issue of *dimensions*, but I have no desire to try to improve the current title.  Anyway, thanks again for improving it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I didn't change it, that was AlexeyPopkov. I don't like the change. As for "no faculty member or potential employer would countenance", I'm self-employed, my customers are primarily at universities, and they seem to appreciate my work. And yes, I do use a bit of whimsey in communication. But consider that I work on space missions that have whimsical names. There's lots of whimsey in the background, too. For example, the TESS testing crew called their setups "ponies" and "dragons". Apparently your corner of the intellectual endeavor is much stuffier. I'm glad I don't work there.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I suggest that you,  AlexeyPopkov, and march read Mermin's fine "E Pluribus Boojum" (http://www.economics.soton.ac.uk/staff/aldrich/boojum.pdf). And lighten up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a bug.  `Fit` tries to create a numerical function with

```
Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{{x, y}},
 {cheb[0, x] cheb[0, y], cheb[0, x] cheb[1, y], cheb[0, y] cheb[1, x], 
  cheb[1, x] cheb[1, y]}, {4}]
(* Experimental`NumericalFunction::dimsl error *)
```

But it should call it without the extra `{}` in the first argument:

```
Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y},
 {cheb[0, x] cheb[0, y], cheb[0, x] cheb[1, y], cheb[0, y] cheb[1, x], 
  cheb[1, x] cheb[1, y]}, {4}]
```

The failure of `CreateNumericalFunction` just means it falls back on some other method of evaluation.